# Trying to remove Chess.app using terminal

Tags: macos

The title says it all. Can I use `sudo rm -r` or `sudo rm -f`?

Comment: Since you don't know what either one does, don't use either one. Instead, provide details of what you are trying to accomplish.  Especially why you think you need to use sudo.

Comment: @MarcWilson I'm trying to remove Chess app. When moving Chess app to trash, is it correct to use `sudo rm -r` or `sudo rm -rf`?

Comment: @MarcWilson Because mac users use `rf` to force empty trash so I would like to move trash without `rf`

Comment: What has trash to do with your question?

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be several questions hidden in your post:

- You can‘t remove `Chess.app` (or any other of the applications installed as part of macOS) without disabling SIP.
- if you are short on disk space look for things which use a lot of space, not for small applications
- `rm -f` is used to remove several files and ignore any errors which might occur
- `rm -r` is used to remove folders and their content (recursively)